# When embedding CLIPS into C Language, what function can used to modify the fact from C program

Tags: c, clips

I have embedded CLIPS into C Language program, I want to modify the facts for example change a certain slot value, which function can I use from C language Program. Otherwise I have to clean all the facts and assert new facts to implement my goal.

Thanks for any idea and suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Section 4.4 of the Advanced Programming Guide, http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/OnlineDocs.html, has a list of functions that can be used on facts. The fact-set queries and distributed actions in section 12.9.12 of the Basic Programming Guide are also useful for retrieving and manipulating facts from a C program. For example, you could use the following function call to retrieve all person deftemplate facts where the value in the age slot was greater than 18:

```
   DATA_OBJECT result;

   Eval("(find-all-facts ((?p person)) (> ?p:age 18))",&result);
```

Comment: I think Eval function is helpful. If there is only one fact match, is the result actually a generic pointer to a fact data structure.

Comment: No. It will be a multifield value with a single field, just as it would be if you entered the expression at the CLIPS> command prompt.

Comment: @GaryRiley Is there any function that allows to modify a given fact by using a C API?  When I try to use `EnvEval("(modify 2 (state fault))")` I get the following error: _Fact-indexes can only be used by modify as a top level command_.

Comment: @gliderkite There's not an easy way to do it. You can use the EnvCreateFact function to create a new fact, change the appropriate values, and then copy the other values from the original fact. You can work around the modify restriction with EnvEval by using do-fact-fact: EnvEval("(do-for-fact ((?f sensor)) (= (fact-index ?f) 2) (modify ?f (state fault)))");