# clips 6.3 CLIPSDLL.h How to modify a fact from c?

Tags: clips

I use clips 6.3. (CLIPSDynamic32) shared dll

```
#include "CLIPSDLL.h"
#include "cstrcpsr.h"
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "clips.h"
Environment *theEnv;

void main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int ret;
    theEnv = __CreateEnvironment();
    int status = __Load(theEnv, "H:\\ClipsIntegrationExample\\clips1.clp");

    __Reset(theEnv);
    __AssertString(theEnv, "(templ1(name1 yes))");
    __Run(theEnv,-1);


    __DestroyEnvironment(theEnv);
    getch();
}
```

This is clips file clp

```
(deftemplate MAIN::templ1
    (slot name1))
```

How to modify a fact from c?

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the fact index of the fact created by AssertString and then construct a string which can be passed to the Eval function to modify the fact. For example:

```
"(do-for-fact ((?f templ1)) (= (fact-index ?f) 2) (modify ?f (name1 xyz)))"
```

See also [When embedding CLIPS into C Language, what function can used to modify the fact from C program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22857868/when-embedding-clips-into-c-language-what-function-can-used-to-modify-the-fact)